# error in pipe implementation , i am facing this error, ls: write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I made this while implementing shell in c,but though while implementing pipes , i came up with this error ls:write error :Bad file descriptor ,and i am not understanding why this error is coming up,
Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void  execute(char **argv)
{
  pid_t  pid;
  int    status;
  //fflush(0); 
  pid_t id  ;
  int out=0,in=0,pip=0;
  int fds[2];

  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
      printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  if (pid==0) {
    close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
    dup2(fds[1],1);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
    close(fds[0]); /* we don't need this */
    execlp(argv[0],argv[0],argv[1],NULL);
   } 
  else {
     close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
     dup2(fds[0],0);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
     close(fds[1]); /* we don't need this */
     execlp(argv[3],argv[3],argv[4], NULL);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a call to `pipe(fds);` before you call `fork()`.  You are also missing some `close()` calls.  If you duplicate one end of a pipe (with `dup()` or `dup2()`) to standard input or standard output, you should close *both* the original descriptors from `pipe()`.

There's also a strong argument that you should check the return values from your system calls.  You could use a function like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...);

void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, " (%d: %s)", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

You can use it like:

```
if (dup2(fds[2], 1) != 0)
    err_exit("dup2(%d, %d) failed", fds[2], 1);
```